# Amazon EC2 Hosted Website Timeout - can't connect on reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, timeout

I was uploading a large folder of files (Zend library) to my ec2 hosted website and WinSCP timed out.  I soon found that my site is down and I can't access winSCP or the console.  I tried to reboot the instance from the amazon console, but the reboot didn't change the situation.

When I visit the website in firefox, here's the error message - The connection has timed out.  The server at domain.com is taking too long to respond.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can reset or fix this?

Notes:  It's been maybe 10 minutes since I rebooted, not sure how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Amazon and ask them. Perhaps they are having an outage?